# JUNIT: setUp() not called

Tags: junit, nullpointerexception, junit5

The `setUp()` of Junit is not called and therefore a `NullPointerException` is thrown when the test methods try to acces the `BankAccount` object.

What is wrong with my `setUp()`?

Here is the **test code**:

```
package my_package;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class BankAccountTest {
    private BankAccount acc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        acc = new BankAccount(100);
    }

    @Test
    void testDeposit() {
        acc.deposit(50);
        assertEquals(acc.getBalance(), 50);
    }

    @Test
    void testWithdraw() {
        acc.withdraw(50);
        assertEquals(acc.getBalance(), 25);
    }

    @Test
    void testWithdrawLimit() {
        assertFalse(acc.withdraw(10000));
        assertEquals(100, acc.getBalance());

        assertTrue(acc.withdraw(1));
        assertEquals(acc.getBalance(),99);
    }
}
```

and here is the **application code**:

```
package my_package;

public class BankAccount {

    private int balance;

    public BankAccount(int i) {
        balance=i;
    }

    public BankAccount() {
        balance=0;
    }

    public void deposit(int amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public boolean withdraw(int amount) {
        boolean allow = balance >= amount;
        if(allow) {
            balance -= amount;  
        }
        return allow;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bank_app_lynda_tdd.BankAccountTest.testWithdraw(BankAccountTest.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Can you also show an example run with the full stacktrace?

Comment: Of course, I also provided the code for someone to reproduce the error.

Comment: Yup, your code example is great! As for some tips: add `System.out.println('HERE');` or something like that in `setUp()` to see if it is called. For additional debugging tips, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for more tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: `BankAccountTest.java:23` What is line 23?

Comment: Line 23 -> `acc.withdraw(50);`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added some console logs before, I just didn't post it here to avoid redundant code. That's where I noticed setUp() is not called. Should I restart Eclipse?

Comment: Replace `@Before` annotation with [`@BeforeEach`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeEach.html)

Comment: @caco3 Nope... Really wtf is going on?

Comment: @caco3 Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @Themelis Must be a difference between JUnit4 vs JUnit5.

Comment: Since I am new to unit testing @Code-Apprentice, does anyone use JUnit4 anymore?

Comment: @Themelis It has been a long time since I did much Java dev. I don't know what's used these days. In general, I prefer learning the most recent version of a library unless there are other constraints.

Comment: You're right @Code-Apprentice.

Comment: @Themelis Feel free to post an answer with the fix. This will likely be closed soon as a "typo".

Comment: Maybe @caco3 was right all along.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice About the `@BeforeEach`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've posted an answer. Thanks

Comment: @Themelis is the issue resolved?

Comment: Yes its resolved @caco3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace [`@Before`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Before.html) annotation with [`@BeforeEach`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeEach.html)

**Explanation**

The `setUp` method uses `@Before` annotation which is from JUnit4.

But your tests are written for JUnit 5 (the [`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Test.html) is used on test methods)

---

From [JUnit5 user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips):

> `@Before` and `@After` no longer exist; use `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` instead